# Repeat two rows pattern in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to mimic this pattern (over and over):

[image]

So I wrote `grid-template-columns: 65% 35%` for the first row. Yet, I want to do  `grid-template-columns: 65% 35%` for a second row (and the fourth, and the sixth and so on), but I'm not sure how can I do that while maintaining `65%` and `35%`.

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rely on `nth-child` selector to do this. Note how the pattern is repeating each 4 elements.

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35% 1fr 35%;
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.child {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.child:nth-child(4n+1),
.child:nth-child(4n+4){
  grid-column:span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div
```

You can also do the same consider only `fr` unit. The result won't be exactly the same `fr` and `%` aren't resolved the same way.

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3.5fr 3fr 3.5fr;  /* 3.5 + 3.5 + 3 = 10*/
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.child {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.child:nth-child(4n+1),
.child:nth-child(4n+4){
  grid-column:span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating a three-column grid with `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.333%);` and adding an additional class for the children that will stretch the element into two columns `grid-column: span 2;`

**Result:**

https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/vYBaZQb

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.333%);
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.child {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.wide {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child wide"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child wide"></div>
  <div class="child wide"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child wide"></div>
  </div
```

[image]